# Wait until login or wrong password

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, wait

I'm trying to automatice some logins in multiple urls with selenium in python 3 but some of them load too slowly when the password is correct. I can't confirm the successful login even with a 60s time sleep. Is there a way to use a wait until something changes in the page? thanks for helping.

```
for url in urls:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        for usuario in objarray:
            driver.find_element_by_id("loginEdit-el").send_keys(usuario.username)
            driver.find_element_by_id("passwordEdit-el").send_keys(usuario.password)
            driver.find_element_by_id('t-comp14-textEl').click()
            time.sleep(15)
            try:
                elemento = driver.find_elements_by_id("menu-button-imageEl")
                if elemento[0] != []:
                    usuario.loginCheck.append('True')
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: would you share some code to show us what you have tried?  that will make it easier for us to help.  Also, have you tried Selenium?

Comment: Yes, in selenium you have option to Wai until an element arrive. Have a look https://www.google.com/search?q=python+selenium+wait+for+element&oq=python+selenium+w&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j35i39j0l2.5918j0j4&client=ms-android-bell-ca&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

If the failed login message shows right after the attempt, track it down and retry. if not do a endless wait for a element present in the next page.

```
def check_exists_by_id(id):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

while check_exists_by_id('next_page_element_id') == False:
    print('Waiting for element')
    time.sleep(1)
```